# Text exceed from cover page, how to solve it?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have brought the title, which is a bit long sentence in cover page.
However, it exceeds the page width, how to correct it? Thanks

```
\vspace{30mm} \centerline{{\bf Title BLAH Blah}}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the `center` environment, as it allows natural wrapping at within the text block:

```
\begin{center}
  \bfseries
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit \ldots
\end{center}
```

Note the use of `\bfseries` rather than `\bf`:

- [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764)
- [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf` , `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help